# "Out of memory on device" with cumsum on gpuArray

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu, cumsum

I am attempting to perform a cumulative sum using MATLAB's cumsum function on 22000x22000 gpuArray filled with -1s,0s and 1s. I am using an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780 Ti which has 3GB of memory. A double-precision gpuArray is too large (3.9GB) but naturally the single precision fits.

Attempting to do a cumsum on my single-precision gpuArray again resulted in reaching my memory limit, but I am not sure if this is due to memory types or the approach to calculating cumsum as it is a MATLAB p-file. This also means regardless I have little control over the datatypes used for calculation. Edit: Also cumsum does not support integer datatypes. Edit: On further inspection the result of performing this on a reduced array is a single, so highly likely function operates on array as input type.

So my question is: is there an alternative to cumsum? (not loops - see note) Whether through MATLAB or CUDA that allows specification of datatype. Or can someone outline how to vectorise (matricise?) the cumsum operation so I can write it myself?

EDIT: Alternative must be able to operate on integer types as just producing the CUM matrix will exceed memory limit. 2xsingle = double...

NOTE: Given I will be performing this computation a significant number of times (no bound presented in paper) I would ideally have the >200x speed increase of cumsum(gpuArray) vs cumsum(double). And don't even mention loops, ridiculously slow.

```MATLAB
tic;CUM = cumsum(W,2);toc
Elapsed time is 0.002180 seconds.

K = gather(W);
tic;CUM = cumsum(K,2);toc
Elapsed time is 0.125203 seconds.
```

Comment: Do you have some code to post? It appears your question got posted with missing information.

Comment: Apologies JoelC, it's my first post and I accidentally hit enter!

Edit contains the rest of question and code with timings.

Comment: A couple of things come to mind: You can try int16 instead of single, you can split your array into, say, 4 chunks that are each small enough to permit the calculation (this reduces the speed increase somewhat, but at least it runs)

Comment: Again apologies, I included the edit about integer data types (not compatible with cumsum). So my issue extends to even just adding another matrix of this size, CUM, as 2xsingle = double

Comment: In the C and C++ implementations that Matlab with GPU is based on, basic integer types and single precision floating point use the same space per element (4 bytes).  Your 22000x22000 matrix will require ~2GB for storage.  If the operation is not done in-place (i.e. if the output is not the same as the input) then you'll run out of memory.  If the algorithm in question uses O(n) temporary storage (might be the case for CUDA based implementations in Thrust or CUB) then you'll run out of memory.

Comment: Don't forget that ECC-ON mode consumes ~12% of GPU memory

Comment: @user2052436  ECC is not an option on a GTX 780 Ti (or any GeForce GPU).

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to be using the values -1, 0, and 1 in your matrix, you can get away using a byte of memory using the signed 8-bit integer type int8 which allows numbers -128 to 127. (With only the options of -1,0 and 1, you could technically fit four values into one byte with 2-bits each, but you may only need to do that if you're still running out of memory).

So if you want to initialise your array with int8's, you can do this:

```
gpuArray = zeros(22000,22000,'int8');
```

Which should be <500MB in size.

Comment: Thanks @can_of_awe. Unfortunately this doesn't suit my purposes: 

"Error using cumsum
CUMSUM is not supported for integer input"

Answer (score 1):

just a remark, timing your code like this is not correct, when dealing with `gpuArray`. You should time it like this

```
tic;CUM = cumsum(W,2);wait(gpuDevice());toc
```

Otherwise, `MATLAB` doesn't count the actually computation, because it isn't needed for the CPU timing function `toc` to execute.

Just a remark for your timing.

For less memory consumption, you can use

```
W = gpuArray(rand(22000,22000,'uint8'));
```

This works for the `cumsum` on the GPU device.